# Dynamic parameter insertion to filter data in iframed dashboard from with in webapp

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We have a web applicaiton used by over 1000 customers.

We would like the abilitu to assist over customers to analyse their account level information i.e. Spend analysis, account overview, product overview.

What we are looking to find a way of passing a customer ID to a query datasaet that pulls customer specific information from the database and binds it to the published iframed power bi dashboard on the go.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to design a generic report on Power BI desktop using the Customer ID as a report level filter. Then, when you embed the report in your web app, you can set the filter to each customer's ID by passing it as a parameter on the embed report URL:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed
?reportId=d2a0ea38-...-9673-ee9655d54a4a&
$filter={tableName/fieldName}%20eq%20'{fieldValue}'
```

(from Power BI embedded [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/#filter-reports-embedded-in-your-application))
If you need more ability to interact with your report I'd recommend the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-interact-with-reports/) on the JavaScript API for Power BI Embedded.